# How to py2exe cefpython3?

Tags: python, py2exe

I've made a small app using cefpython3 (CEF3 for python) with Python 2.7 which runs fine on its own.

When I try to py2exe it I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myapp.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "zipextimporter.pyc", line 82, in load_module
  File "cefpython3\__init__.pyc", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name cefpython_py27
```

I tried adding cefpython3 to includes, but in the library.zip I only see the `__init__.pyc`, copying all the files from cefpython3 there does not solve this either.

Comment: Does Python3 support Py2exe?

Comment: This would be Python 2.7, cefpython3 is a confusing name since it's cef3 for python. it comes in two, one being 2.7 and one being 3.2.

Comment: Could you ever sort this out? I have the same issue

Comment: have you tried pyinstaller or cx_freeze? they seem to find packages better than py2exe.

Comment: I just tried both, neither successfully picked up cefpython. Could not get PyInstaller to pick it up even when told manually what was necessary.